# CORS blocking post from jQuery

Tags: jquery, python, flask, cors, uwsgi

I am trying to post from a static page that pretends to be a remote web server into my `Flask` app, running behind `uwsgi` because of `Flask-uWSGI-WebSocket`.

Every time I post to my server, the post is blocked because of CORS:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:5000/tnw/post. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

I've installed `flask-cors` and origins is set to `*` but I still can't get it to go through. What else am I missing here?

My POST:

`$("#ajaxbutton").click(function() {
    var json = JSON.stringify(generate_json());
    $.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/tnw/post', json);
});`

Comment: How are you accessing the page that makes the CORS request? Is it via http:// or file:// (the latter will give you an origin of 'null', which you do not want). If the latter, try using a simple http server instead (e.g. python -m SimpleHTTPServer). Also, are you requiring any kind of authentication on this endpoint? If so, and it's cookie-based, you'll need to set the `withCredentials` xhr field to `true` to allow the cookie to be posted with the request ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)).

Comment: Which was the issue? Adding an answer now, but I'd like to make sure it addresses the correct issue for future readers.

Comment: I was accessing it through file://

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see this being one of two problems:

- You're accessing the page that makes the CORS request over the `file://` protocol instead of `http://`. This causes you to have an `origin` of `'null'`. Try using accessing it via `http://` instead (e.g. `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`).
- Does your endpoint require cookie-base authentication? jQuery omits cookies on CORS requests by default. If you need to send cookies with your request, add `{xhrFields: withCredentials: true}` to your ajax requests ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)).